# Please write this simple regexp for me

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried a couple things but I can't get a working regex. In JavaScript lookbehind does not seem to work. I have the following output of version info:

```
Version: 1.0

Java SDK
--------
java version "1.7.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.3.4.el6_5-x86_64 u45-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)`
```

I need to get the

```
1.0
```

from it via regex. Does anyone has an idea how to achieve this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it poster made no attempt to solve the (trivially simple) problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use capturing groups. First captured group contains the string `1.0`,

```
Version:\s*([\d.]+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bL1cV0/8)